# Django modelform how to add a confirm password field?

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, password-confirmation

Here I need to add an extra `confirmation password` in my form.I used Django's modelform. I also need to validate both passwords. It must raise a validation error if `password1 != password2`.

Here is my forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    YESNO_CHOICES = (('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female'))
    sex = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES=(('red','red'),('blue','blue'))
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES)
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), 
                                 input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))

    class Meta:

        model=UserProfile
        fields=('phone','picture','sex','favorite_colors','dob')
```

And here is my registration function:

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)



        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,
            'mysite/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `clean` like

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )
```

Comment: I keep having AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: If you have multiple rules, this will stop at the first error and won't show the other errors, other solution is better IMO

Answer (score 15):

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserAccountForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

    if password != confirm_password:
        self.add_error('confirm_password', "Password does not match")

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks! `add_error()`is much better than `raise forms.ValidationError` so you can display all errors instead of only showing the first error

Answer (score 2):

Try this for forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('username','email','password')
```

And this in views.py:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid() and user_form.cleaned_data['password'] == user_form.cleaned_data['password_confirm']:
    ...
elif user_form.data['password'] != user_form.data['password_confirm']:
    user_form.add_error('password_confirm', 'The passwords do not match')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at how Django does it for UserCreationForm.

```py
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2
```

Here password2 refers to the confirm_password field, under the assumption that it appears after the password field. Trying to use the same implementation for clean_password may lead to an error that the confirm_password data wasn't found.

This has the advantage that you're raising the error for a particular Field, instead of the whole form, which you can then render appropriately in your template.

However, if you're trying to validate data across multiple fields, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) advises overriding the `clean()` method, as answered by Savai.

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py).

Answer (score 0):

Confirm password is already available in UserCreationForm

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
```

This will automatically verify `password1==password2` when form.is_valid() is called.

Here I am only taking email as a separate form arguments for further clean up and validation