# Can we add two password fields for validate password and confirm password using model fields in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Actually i new to django framework. Here my doubt is, can we create two password fields for password validation one is **password** and second is **confirm password** for user registration template or can we manage only one password field. Let anyone please give the clarification for that.

Here is example model:

```
class new_user(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField()
   email = models.EmailField()
   password = models.CharField()
   confirmpassword = models.CharField()
```

or else can we manage only one password field like below :

```
 class new_user(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField()
   email = models.EmailField()
   password = models.CharField()
```

Comment: You may check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609830/django-modelform-how-to-add-a-confirm-password-field

Comment: Actually whatever fields are available in model class that fields we have to take in model form.

Comment: My question is,  how many password fields can I take in model for that validating the password and confirm password in template

Comment: Generally you don't have a `confirmpassword` field on the model because there is no need to store the value.  `password` and `confirmpassword` are compared in the view; if they match, save `password`, if they don't, tell the user there's a problem.  In either case, `confirmpassword` can be discarded once the comparison has taken place.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks. Actually I am looking for this kind of answer. Could please elaborate the answer with few more lines..